# save file in debugging file in android

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I would like to save an image to disk someplace for debugging.

```
  String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path + "/android.png");
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
```

When I do this I get a permissions error when I try to save. What Am I doing wrong?

03-29 17:06:32.328: WARN/System.err(2276): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/android.png (Permission denied)

Comment: did you set the permission in the manifest?

Comment: The `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in particular.

Comment: and the emulator was created with SD card support / phone has external storage? (sorry for asking dumb questions, just to be sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters indicate, either:

- You do not have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` properly defined (e.g., it's in the wrong spot in the manifest)
- External storage is not available (e.g., it is mounted on your host machine)